# Warning - Type library 'System_Windows_Forms' was exported from a CLR assembly and cannot be re-imported as a CLR assembly

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF application, using VS2022, I wanted to consider using the FolderBrowserDialog, so added System_Windows_Forms reference.
I decided not to use FolderBrowserDialog, and don't need this reference.
I can find no instance of reference to Forms in my solution. FolderBrowserDialog is not used.
This warning persists.
Right-click on project -> Remove Unused References does not help ("No unused references were found").
Closing VS and re-opening does not help.
Deleting the .obj directory does not help.
It's just a warning, and the program runs just fine.
Any ideas on how to fix this?


Edit:

I initially added reference by right-clicking project -> Add -> COM Reference, then selecting System_Windows_Forms, version 2.4.


Edit #2: .csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>BKMorse2</RootNamespace>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <StartupObject>BKMorse2.App</StartupObject>
    <ApplicationIcon>Resources\CodeKey1.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <BaseOutputPath>C:\Users\bkrau\OneDrive\Desktop\BK Morse 2\Any CPU\Release</BaseOutputPath>
    <BaseIntermediateOutputPath></BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
    <Title>BK Morse 2</Title>
    <PackageProjectUrl>Copyright BK Morse 2022</PackageProjectUrl>
    <PackageIcon>Resources\CodeKey1.ico</PackageIcon>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>Initial Release</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>True</EnforceCodeStyleInBuild>
    <AnalysisLevel>6.0-all</AnalysisLevel>
    <NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.2</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.2</FileVersion>
    <UseWindowsForms>False</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
    <WarningLevel>7</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>False</Optimize>
    <WarningLevel>7</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="ARRL512.png" />
    <None Remove="CheckPng.png" />
    <None Remove="morse-code.ico" />
    <None Remove="Resources\BKMorse2ScreenshotWithNumbers.jpg" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Enter Copy Text Here.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\EnterTextHere.gif" />
    <None Remove="Resources\FolderClosed.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\NewEvent.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\play-outline.png" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Play.svg" />
    <None Remove="Resources\Trash.png" />
    <None Remove="Resource\ARRLSessions.xml" />
    <None Remove="Resource\ARRL_diamond_logo.png" />
    <None Remove="Resource\DownArrow.png" />
    <None Remove="Resource\EnterTextHere.gif" />
    <None Remove="Resource\Plus48.png" />
    <None Remove="Resource\RedX.png" />
    <None Remove="Resource\Trashcan48.png" />
    <None Remove="Resource\UpArrow.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}">
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <VersionMinor>4</VersionMinor>
      <VersionMajor>2</VersionMajor>
      <Guid>215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61</Guid>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Resources\CodeKey1.ico" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\.editorconfig" Link=".editorconfig" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Extended.Wpf.Toolkit" Version="4.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Resources\BKMorse2ScreenshotWithNumbers.jpg" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\CodeKey1.jpg" />
    <Resource Include="morse-code.ico" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Enter Copy Text Here.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\EnterTextHere.gif" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\FolderClosed.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\NewEvent.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\play-outline.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Play.svg" />
    <Resource Include="Resources\Trash.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resource\ARRLSessions.xml" />
    <Resource Include="Resource\ARRL_diamond_logo.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resource\CheckPng.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resource\ARRL512.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resource\DownArrow.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resource\EnterTextHere.gif" />
    <Resource Include="Resource\Plus48.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resource\RedX.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resource\Trashcan48.png" />
    <Resource Include="Resource\UpArrow.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Resources.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="Properties\Resources.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Resources.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Resources\CodeKey1.jpg">
      <Pack>True</Pack>
      <PackagePath>\</PackagePath>
    </None>
    <None Update="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project type is "WPF .Net", then the link to the Forms is in the project properties.
I show it in the screenshot, but I immediately warn you that I have a Russian Studio. I think you, however, will understand.
If it is not clear, then write - I will ask someone to take a screenshot in the English Studio.
[image]

**Updating the response after providing the XML content of the project file.**

The only questionable element in my opinion is the group with `<COMReference Include="{215d64d2-031c-33c7-96e3-61794cd1ee61}">`. Try removing it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks. I tried enabling this, then disabling, but still the same error. I initially added reference by right-clicking project -> Add -> COM Reference, then selecting System_Windows_Forms, version 2.4. (updated post to include this)

Comment: @BobKrauth , Please show the contents of the project file "*.csproj"

Comment: Added .csproj file to original post. Thanks.